# CGI with Python2.7

Tags: python, http, webserver, cgi

Am using python2.7. My task is to create a web page say login screen in browser using python. I tried CGI. My code is showing HTML file(all the html code from  to ) in CMD screen. Whereas i want them in browser as web page. Any help?.

Comment: You have to use a webserver in order to be able to render your web page, you cannot just run your code like you would with another python program. Please post your code too.

Comment: A good alternative to CGI is mod_python for Apache.  Then you might want to consider a web framework, there are many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use it as CGI you must move your script into `cgi-bin` or similar directory of HTTP server. Then point your browser into `http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/my_scipt.py` and see results. In case of problems see at HTTP server error log.

In case of strange errors show us what HTTP server and OS you use, example "Apache 2.2 on WinXP".

Comment: Thanks. I have configured CGI in my system.. Placed my code in cgi-bin.. and opened the script in browser..